# Show generated support structures in Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura

In Cura, when you enable "Print support structure", is there a way to see what it will look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the View Modes Button in the upper right hand corner, and select Layers.

[image: Cura]

Comment: Works, looks kind of weird though.  Too bad there isn't an option to show the support structures in normal mode.

Answer (score 2):

Cura generates support based on the outlines of the layers which will be printed, rather based on the triangles of the 3D model.
It is therefore not possible to show the generated support in the solid view.

You can view the support in the layer view however.
In Cura 2 that's on the left bottom of the screen.

[image: Cura]

Support is classified as a helper part in the legend of the layer view.